Issues with Broadcast Receivers and Overlay in Android App for non ordered broadcast
I'm developing an Android app using Kotlin, which includes a background service that opens a transparent overlay using an Android Dialog when an action occurs in a third-party app. My goal is for the third-party app to enter a paused state when my overlay is active, but it doesn't seem to be pausing, and its listeners continue to work.
When the overlay is displayed, I start listening for a specific broadcast intent. However, when a broadcast occurs, both my overlay and the background service receive the intent, leading to unintended actions.
To resolve it I set the priority of my application to the Highest andI tried using abortBroadcast() to abort it but I am getting the error that non-ordered broadcast can not be aborted. Broadcast is still passing to other application.
I also tried to programmatically click on the home button to pause the application but that action is moving the screen to home and I want to use the same application in overlay background as I am performing the action for the same application.
Is there a way to programmatically force the third-party app to pause, or is this behavior entirely up to the app?
I am using the dialog to show an overlay. Is using a Dialog the best approach for showing an overlay, or is there a better way to ensure the third-party app becomes inactive/paused?
I've checked the permissions and ensured that my overlay is displayed correctly.
The broadcast receiver in my app is registered dynamically.

"Is there a way to programmatically force the third-party app to pause, or is this behavior entirely up to the app?" -- you have not defined "paused", other than by "its listeners continue to work", and we do not know what "listeners" you are referring to. If you are defining "paused" as "no longer responds to this broadcast", then that is up to the developers of the third-party app.
